# How can I suppress the Citrix receiver Add Account window on login?

Tags: citrix, citrix-receiver

I have recently installed Citrix Receiver. Every time I login, I get a "Add Account" prompt. I would not like to login.

How can I make this window not show when I login? I would like to make this the default for all users. I would like to be able to add an exception to this for a specific user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save this as a .reg file and [execute](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX135438#Instructions) it once 'As Administrator':

```
REGEDIT4
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Policies\Citrix]
"EnableX1FTU"=dword:00000000
```

When it happens to be a 32-bit machine, leave out the Wow6432Node part.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

> Method 1
>
> Rename `CitrixReceiver.exe` to `CitrixReceiverWeb.exe`. This solution works through both the GUI install and CLI install.

(From [CTX135438: *How to Suppress the Add Account Window in Citrix Receiver for Windows*](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX135438).)

And for an existing installation just remove the single Citrix file from the start menu startup (type Windows+R -> shell:startup -> Press  -> remove link).

**Related:** Thread on Citrix Forums: [*How to suppress “Add Account”?*](https://discussions.citrix.com/topic/374512-how-to-suppress-%E2%80%9Cadd-account%E2%80%9D/)

Comment: How can I make it show again?

Comment: Just double click on the icon in the task tray.

Comment: OK, I'll try it

Comment: I cannot find it in the startup

Comment: Try autoruns: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx